# pull - "Error in make_ansi_style(x[["color"]]) : Unknown style specification: br_magenta"

Tags: r

Whenever I try to run the code `pull` the error message

```
Error in make_ansi_style(x[["color"]]) : 
  Unknown style specification: br_magenta
```

shows up.

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got this error message after I removed the `library(dplyr)`-call and I forgot to change `last(...)` to `dplyr::last(...)`.
Have you tried writing `dplyr::pull()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where exactly this error occurred for you, but today I tried running some of my code from 2 years ago and I suddenly ran into this error, specifically in something like:

```
data %>% group_by(mygroups) %>% dplyr::summarize(min=min(myfeature))
```

The only difference to 2 years ago was that my data now contained some missing values. I could fix it by properly dealing with the missing values, i.e. `min("feat", na.rm=TRUE)`.

But I have no clue why this would cause an "unknown style specification" error or if it is at all related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Data science (i.e. `tidyverse`) methods like `ggplot` and `group_by` requires tidy inputs.
`ggplot` specifically, requires tidy inputs or any input object that `fortify()` can convert to a data frame.
So, it's safe to convert the data you are plotting to a data frame before passing it to `ggplot`.

I once got the same kind of error when trying to plot a graphic with `ggplot` using a numeric vector as input data.

Consider `ggplot`, for instance:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_v <- matrix(rnorm(20*2), ncol=2)
data_clr <- c(rep(-1,10), rep(1,10))

data_v %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=data_v[,1], y=data_v[,2], color=(3-data_clr))) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  xlab("data_v[,1]") +
  ylab("data_v[,2]")
```

Running the code above in **R Notebook** will output the error you mentioned:

```
 Error in make_ansi_style(x[["color"]]) : 
   Unknown style specification: br_magenta
```

But if you run the same code in a **R Script** the output error will be slight different (good info to know) and you will get to the root of the problem. Here what you will get:

```
  Error in `fortify()`:
    ! `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector.
  Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The error happens because `fortify()` is not able to convert the data to a data frame to be used by `ggplot`.

If you run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred, then you will get the weird stuff:

```
rlang::last_trace()

# output:
# Error in make_ansi_style(x[["color"]]) : 
#   Unknown style specification: br_magenta
```

Below a right way to pass data to `ggplot` for this example:

```
## CORRECTED CODE:
library(tidyverse)

data_v <- matrix(rnorm(20*2), ncol=2)
data_clr <- c(rep(-1,10), rep(1,10))

df <- data.frame(data_v)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=df[,1], y=df[,2], color=(3-data_clr))) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  xlab("data_v[,1]") +
  ylab("data_v[,2]")
```

Note: Another way to run into the same type of error is by passing unstructured data to the color argument instead. In the example below I pass a vector containing only 2 data points to the color argument.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_v <- matrix(rnorm(20*2), ncol=2)

data.frame(data_v) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=data_v[,2], y=data_v[,1], color=c("red","blue"))) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  xlab("data_v[,2]") +
  ylab("data_v[,1]")

# Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
#   ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): colour
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

rlang::last_trace()

# Error in make_ansi_style(x[["color"]]) : 
#   Unknown style specification: br_magenta
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and resolved it by importing the stringr R library.

```
library(stringr)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's masking some other error, i.e. it wants to give you a fancy traceback with colors but errors while looking for the colors. The solution is to

```
install.packages("cli")
```

which provides the functions that allow for the fancy traceback with colors.